# Execute mgo.Pipe without results, including $out

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Im trying to run a Pipe that doesn't return any results, because the last pipeline operator is `$out`.

```
// { $out: "y" } 
pipeline := DB. C("x"). Pipe(stages). AllowDiskUse() 
result := []bson.M{}
err := pipeline.All(&result)
```

When running the pipe with I'm getting a timeout. I assume mgo is waiting for results to be read - forever.

Comment: You have to pass a pointer to `Pipe.All()` like: `pipeline.All(&result)`. Also, what is `stages`?

Comment: I'm on my mobile, sorry. I am actually passing a pointer, updating the question. Stages is a `[]bson.M`, which gets constructed from json files. It contains the `$out` operator. Aggregation is running OK, according to mongo shell, but still `All` fails after the output collection has been populated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Instead of calling `All(&result)`, call `Iter()`.

`All` would call `Next` on an iterator that is empty from the beginning, obviously leading to the timeout.

`Iter` returns an iterator, that will just get discarded. No calls to `Next`, no timeouts.